# Difference between write method in ViewController and AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to ask a simple question as i am new in Objective c.
Is there are any difference to write method on AppDelegate instead of UIViewController??

Or which type of method i should write on AppDelegate.
And what if i write method in UIViewController and call from AppDelegate.

Is there are safe to write method on UIViewConroller class and call it from AppDelegate.m file by that UIViewController's object.???

If i write it on ViewController and call it from AppDelegate.m then is it safe or not???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **AppDelegate** is shared singleton class. 
That means appdelegate object will be created only once in your entire app life cycle.

Creating method in AppDelegate is recommended when you have to process something multiple times in your application and that method may be called through viewcontroller, from appdelegate itself or other singleton class.

Like. Process zip archive, Check version of iOS device

And yes **Most important thing**
This can also be done in other ways.

However if you want to call **viewcontroller** method from **AppDelegate** you need to create an object of viewcontroller or get viewcontroller object from memory. And there should be some solid reason to do that.

It depends on your app **Architecture** and **Requirement**.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Dhaval you can write and call method from any where in your project but for that you have to define the function definition in .h file and that make this function global for the project.

Next thing is that when you define any function in app delegate it access by it share instance because app delegate instance live still your application is not terminate.